# my author of the comment is showing null django

Tags: django, django-models

The author of the post is shown correctly but when I use the same for comment it is returning NULL instead of the author.
models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
class BlogPost(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null=False,blank=False)
   #body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000 , null=False,blank=False)
   body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True,null= True)
   date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   #slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,unique=True)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('post:article-detail', args=(self.id,))

 class comment(models.Model):
    BlogPost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s  %s' % (self.BlogPost.title, self.name)
```

if "null=True" is not written in the author field then it it giving me this error "NOT NULL constraint failed: post_comment.author_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe this is being caused by the fact that you added the author field to Comments after it was created. Or that the author field is empty for one or more of the records in your DB.

What happens in this scenario is that if the field has null=True. You will get that the author is null (because currently in your DB there is no author to those comments).

if null=False then Django will throw an error because those fields cannot be empty and cannot be null